# Technology of WinHex

Tags: qt

I am going to create Win Hex like application in Qt. I want to know which widget should I use for creating hex display area.  I have to open hard disk in it so it would be a very large number of lines for displaying 500 GB of disk.

So, which widget can handle this large number of hexadecimal lines?

I have started to do it in `QWidget`'s paint event but the height of `QWidget` is in integer so number of lines could not be greater than the range of integer.

So, should I use `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit`?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to be loading the *entire* file/disk data into the editor. Most editors capable of handling large files or editing whole disks would instead likely load only the area currently being displayed, handling scroll events to read and display the area being scrolled to.

Comment: So please tell me how to manage scroll events how to control when i do some changes in a sector & then go to an other sector then at the time of undo how to get that at which place I go & do undo, by using Qundo stack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong way. Consider to use QAbstractItemModel + QTableView. Your model can use "virtual window". It means that your model holds only small piece of data which will be loaded on demand.

Comment: qt model view concept can be found at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html

Comment: Here I have to use Undo facility also & i have to change the hex characters ,,.. Using Qundo stack & Qundo commands.
The requirement is to have total sectors at a single scroll area .. this is not going to done if i use QAbstract item model....

Comment: please tell me can I create undo facility with this , because I have to display hard disk in qscrollarea.